# Using the stripe checkout button with Parse.js and cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I am having a serious issue as I cannot seem to figure out how to integrate the stripe checkout button with my Parse.js web app. I have successfully integrated a custom form with stripe, however I want to use the button because I like the simplicity of it and the way it looks.

The below works:

```
## 

<form action="" style="display:none" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                       <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                       <div class="form-group">

                               <label class="light">Card Number<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                               <input  class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="1234567890123456" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>

                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">

                           <label class="light">CVC<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                           <input class="form-control"  placeholder="354" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>

                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">

                           <label class="light">EXP<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                           <input class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="03" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>

                         <span> / </span>
                         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="17" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                       </div>

                       <button class="btn btn-mega btn-lg" onClick="submit">Enter Contest!</button>
                      </form>
          <script type="text/javascript">

               Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_4alV695khm3Vq9kEUfj89JeQ');

           </script>
       <script>
           jQuery(function($) {
       $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
     var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);


    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
        });
       });
      </script>

    <script>
         function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {


    var $form = $('#payment-form');

  console.log('Stripe responding..');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {


    // and submit
Parse.initialize("wuFIoY6zX3Al8zV7QuBLgA0z4W2JjeeTvfQkEvoe", "Tgyj2r9Jhx42ec5PJb2HbJeZWaaHScPYimnd8Jyv");
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    console.log('Token: ' + token);
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    //$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("products");
      var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);

      query.equalTo("product_id", getUrlVars()["prod"]);
      query.first({
        success: function(object) {



           var currentUser1 = Parse.User.current();

           Parse.Cloud.run('enterproductwithid', { "token": token, "objId": object.id, "        username": currentUser1.getUsername()  }, {
           success: function(success) {
            // ratings should be 4.5
        alert('success' + success);

      },
      error: function(error) {

        alert('error: ' + error);
        console.log('There has been a stripe error.');
      }
      });





  },
  error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });


  }
};
</script>
```

The above works fine, I am trying to make the below work the same. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
          <form id="payment-form" action="javascript:updasteform();" u method="POST" >
                   <script
                     src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                     data-key="pk_test_4alV695khm3Vq9kEUfj89JeQ"
                     data-amount="2000"
                     data-name="Demo Site"
                     data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
                     data-image="/128x128.png"
                     data-zip-code="Enter Zip">


                    </script>






          </form>
```

Comment: You probably want to fix the spelling of `action="javascript:updasteform();"`, but I have no idea if that is related.

Comment: Thanks, but no, not related, I could name that function anything.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to solve the same problem.